# Using an iPad or Nexus 7 as an Ubuntu Second Monitor

Tags: monitor, ipad

Is there any way to use an iPad mini or a Nexus 7 as a second monitor through a cable? I don't want something like vnc, I need it to work through the usb cable (or any other cable).

The reason why I am considering the iPad is because of the larger screen (compared to the Nexus 7). I think its self explanatory that I need this to work with Ubuntu.

Comment: Keep in mind that anything that works on the nexus 7 will probably work on the nexus 10.

Comment: My attempt at clarifying this question.  

Looking for a way to use Nexus 7 / 10 as a second monitor with Ubuntu desktop - to extend the Ubuntu desktop to the Nexus 7.

In manner similar to methods described for these Mac and windows desktops: http://mashable.com/2012/11/01/tablet-second-monitor/